# Управлять фоновыми задачами (BackgroundService) через контроллеры (ControllerBase)

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-8.0

- Стоит задача создать файловый менеджер, используя `SMB`.
- Для создания сервера SMB решил использовать: [SMBLibrary](https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary)
- Для управления библиотекой решил использовать `asp net core`.
- Для решения данной задачи: решил использовать `BackgroundService : IHostedService`.

В итоге столкнулся с проблемой, что в интернете очень большое количество информации и примеров про создание длительной фоновой задачи (`BackgroundService`), однако мне не удалось найти информацию и примеры по управлению данным классом.

---

- Во-первых, я хочу иметь возможность выключать и включать `SMB` сервер, а значит включать и выключать фоновый процесс `BackgroundService`.
- Во-вторых, я хочу иметь возможно, без перезагрузки фонового процесса, вносить изменения в общие папки и пользователей (библиотека такую возможность предоставляет).

---

Для создания `SMB` сервера нужно использовать класс `SMBLibrary.Server.SMBServer`:

```cs
// Общие папки
var shares = new SMBShareCollection();

// Пользователи
var users = new GSSProvider(authenticationMechanism);

// Создание сервера
var server = new SMBServer(shares, users);
server.Start();
```

---

Главные вопросы у меня такие:

- Как можно управлять фоновыми задачами (включать и выключать их) используя `Controller`?
- Возможно ли использовать переменные фоновой задачи?

---

Примеры кода для понимания:

```cs
public class SMBServerService : BackgroundService
{
    public SMBShareCollection Shares { get; set; }
    public GSSProvider Users { get; set; }
    public SMBServer Server { get; set; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Server = new SMBServer(Shares, Users);
        Server.Start();
    }
}
```

Контроллер включения/выключения сервера:

```cs
// Хочу иметь возможность использовать переменные сервиса в контроллерах
// Для понимания ниже код контроллера управления

// Примечание: я не понимаю, как передать SMBServerService в контроллер,
// А затем использовать его переменные.

[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class StateController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Task Disable()
    {
        // Останавливаю сервер
        SMBServerService.Server.Stop();
        return Task.CompliteTask;
    }

    public Task Enable()
    {
        // Включаю сервер
        SMBServerService.Server.Start();
        return Task.CompliteTask;
    }
}
```

Контроллер управления пользователями:

```cs
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    public Task AddUser([FromFrom] User user)
    {
        SMBServerService.Users.Add(user);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: По первому вопросу, через Dependency Injection. По второму, да, в первом примере кода у вас уже прописаны публичные свойства. По DI регистрируйте как singleton, чтобы один экземпляр `SMBServerService` использовался во всём жизненном цикле программы, либо же рассмотрите другие варианты: scoped, transient…